# How to POST multiple {json.api} format objects to Django model?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, bulkinsert

Here are the snippets of my code,

Model `OptionalFieldsByOrganization.py`

```
from django.db import models

from model_utils import Choices

from proposal.models import Organization
from proposal.models.proposal_configurable_fields import ProposalConfigurableFields


class OptionalFieldsByOrganization(models.Model):
    STATUS = Choices(
        (0, 'hidden', 'Hidden'),
        (1, 'optional', 'Optional'),
        (2, 'required', 'Required'))

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    configurable_fields = models.ForeignKey(ProposalConfigurableFields, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS.hidden)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_optionalfieldsbyorganization', 'Can view Optional Fields By Organization'),)
```

Serializer

```
from rest_framework_json_api import serializers
from proposal.models import (
organization, proposal_configurable_fields)
from rest_framework_json_api.relations import ResourceRelatedField

from proposal.models import OptionalFieldsByOrganization


class OptionalFieldsByOrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OptionalFieldsByOrganization
        #fields = ['status']
        fields = "__all__"
```

ViewSet

```
from sis_common.views import BaseViewSet
from proposal.models import organization

from proposal.serializers.optional_fields_by_organization import (
    OptionalFieldsByOrganizationSerializer)
from proposal.models.optional_fields_by_organization import (
    OptionalFieldsByOrganization)


class OptionalFieldsByOrganizationViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    queryset = OptionalFieldsByOrganization.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    serializer_class = OptionalFieldsByOrganizationSerializer
```

With this configuration in place, I'm able to fetch multiple records in an array. Like this,

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8000/v1/optionalfieldsbyorganizations \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
{
    "links": {
        "first": "http://localhost:8000/v1/optionalfieldsbyorganizations?page%5Bnumber%5D=1",
        "last": "http://localhost:8000/v1/optionalfieldsbyorganizations?page%5Bnumber%5D=1",
        "next": null,
        "prev": null
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "OptionalFieldsByOrganization",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "status": 0
            },
            "relationships": {
                "organization": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Organization",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "configurable_fields": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "ProposalConfigurableFields",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "OptionalFieldsByOrganization",
            "id": "2",
            "attributes": {
                "status": 1
            },
            "relationships": {
                "organization": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Organization",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "configurable_fields": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "ProposalConfigurableFields",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "OptionalFieldsByOrganization",
            "id": "3",
            "attributes": {
                "status": 0
            },
            "relationships": {
                "organization": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Organization",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                },
                "configurable_fields": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "ProposalConfigurableFields",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pages": 1,
            "count": 3
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to bulk post and patch for the same resource. The payload will look like this,

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "OptionalFieldsByOrganization",
            "attributes": {
                "status": 2
            },
            "relationships": {
                "organization": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Organization",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                },
                "configurable_fields": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "ProposalConfigurableFields",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            "type": "OptionalFieldsByOrganization",
            "attributes": {
                "status": 1
            },
            "relationships": {
                "organization": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Organization",
                        "id": "2"
                    }
                },
                "configurable_fields": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "ProposalConfigurableFields",
                        "id": "3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
}
```

What all changes should I make in my code to achieve this?
I read about `extensions` in {json.api} however, not sure how to make use of it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one possible approach could as follows. If you insist on sending the object in "data" field of your request.

Create a special view to handle bulk create a do this in post method:

```
class BulkView(generics.GenericAPIView):

   serializer_class = OptionalFieldsByOrganizationSerializer
   queryset = OptionalFieldsByOrganization.objects.all()

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ser = self.get_serializer(data=request.data["data"], many=True)

       ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

       ser.save()

       return Response(ser.data)
```

Comment: Before it reaches the view the JSONParser should parse and mark it as validated data. If the parsing fails, the data won't be available? Correct me if I'm wrong.